# Protect one worksheet with a password from showing up

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a built-in way in Excel to protect just one spreadsheet in a Workbook with a Password?

Something like when user ticks or selects a Control , a password is prompted before a Worksheet become visible.

If its not built into Excel, can it be implemented with VBA?

Comment: This is all well-documented on the Microsoft website, please refer to this: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/password-protect-worksheet-or-workbook-elements-HP010078580.aspx

Comment: You are not helping the OP. OP wishes to block the user from VIEWING the worksheet at all.

Comment: @Shorn Jacob: I have never tried this but I would look into capturing the Worksheet_Activate event, prompt the user and if the correct password is not entered, return the user to another sheet (perhaps the previous sheet which you can store using that same event).

Answer (score 2):

You could try this approach which:

- Makes the sheet `VeryHidden` and `Protected` so that it can't be unprotected - or detected - from the standard xl menus
- Adds back in this protection on the `Workbook_BeforeClose` and `Workbook_Open` events
- I haved used a sheet called *YourSheet* for this example
- You should protect the VBA in this project as well to add further security.

Insert an `Active X` checkbox and use code to check if:

1. The checkbox is True
2. The user knows the password to `UnHide` the sheet. (*Fred* is used in this example)

**CheckBox code**

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    Dim StrPass As String
    If CheckBox1.Value Then
        StrPass = Application.InputBox("Please enter the password", "Admin check")
        If StrPass = "fred" Then
            With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("YourSheet")
                .Unprotect "fred"
                .Visible = xlSheetVisible
                MsgBox "Sheet unhidden!", vbInformation
            End With
        Else
            MsgBox "wrong password", vbCritical
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

**the `ThisWorkbook` module**

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("YourSheet")
        .Protect "fred"
        .Visible = xlVeryHidden
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("YourSheet")
        .Protect "fred"
        .Visible = xlVeryHidden
    End With
End Sub
```